# как узнать установленную версию SDK в приложении и изменить ее?

Tags: flutter, dart

Как узнать установленную **Android SDK** в приложении и изменить ее? Я захожу **android/app/src/** файл **build.gradle**. Раньше, там цифрами было указаны версии, сейчас нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Project Structure обычно установлено **No SDK**, я выбрал самую последнюю **Android SDK 32**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скомпилировал приложение, пока все нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь я вручную изменил в файле **build.gradle** версию **Android SDK**, вместо

```
flutter.compileSdkVersion
```

я написал цифрами

```
32
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скомпилировал приложение, приложение работает, но много ошибок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ВОПРОС**. Как правильно узнать установленную версию по умолчанию? Можно ли вот так вручную изменять версии в файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значения по умолчанию зашиты в недрах *Flutter SDK*
в файле **<Flutter SDK path>/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle**.

Например, для версии 2.8.1:

```dart
/** For apps only. Provides the flutter extension used in app/build.gradle. */
class FlutterExtension {
    /** Sets the compileSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int compileSdkVersion = 31

    /** Sets the minSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int minSdkVersion = 16

    /** Sets the targetSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int targetSdkVersion = 31
```

Сделано это в расчете на то, что при смене *Flutter SDK* будут автоматом меняться версии *Android SDK*, что вполне приемлемо для проектов без доработки на уровне платформы. Другое дело, если в Android-проект вносились изменения и они привязаны к определенному диапазону версий. Тут уже надо задавать конкретные значения.

По поводу ошибок точно не скажу, но если Android-проект идет *по наследству* от старых версий и не подвергался доработкам, то можно просто удалить папку **android** и пересоздать её заново командой `flutter create .` (сделав на всякий случай сохранение всего проекта).

Comment: Уважаемый Spatz! Огромное Вам спасибо!